# Классы в папках подключенного проекта не доступны Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, project

Есть решение из нескольких проектов. Ссылки указал с первого и третьего на второй (при этом первый находится в директории решения, а третий нет). Ставлю `using namespace TransCore;`, классы `Link` и `Node` из главной директории проекта доступны, но все классы/интерфейсы в подпапках как и не существуют, хотя они объявлены в том же пространстве имён. Почему так, и как можно исправить?

[image: Решение и проекты]

**UPD.** У первых двух проектов нажатие правой кнопкой мыши открывает такое меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А у третьего такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чем они так отличаются? Тем, что третий вне директории решения?

Comment: перекомпилируйте проект TransCore

Comment: @Igor по непонятной мне причине, иконка у этого проекта не такая, как у тех двух. И, в отличии от них, его не предлагается перекомпилировать, только выгрузить и перезагрузить, что не приносит какого-либо результата.

Comment: using TransCore.Abstract;

Comment: в свойствах проекта посмотрите его тип - должно быть Class Library

Comment: @Mirdin я написал, что те файлы во папках используют только пространство `TransCore`. Хотя я и попробовал добавить директорию через точку, пространства имён такого не нашлось.

Comment: @Igor у меня в свойствах проекта отображаются только корневое пространство имён, папка проекта и его файл. (Кстати, у первых двух проектов файл расширения `.csproj`, а у третьего `.shproj`.)

Comment: А почему бы вам просто не пересоздать этот проект как обыкновенную Class Library? Скопируйте файлы с исходниками и пересоздайте.

Comment: Откройте непосредственно исходник, любого класса и проверьте два пункта: 1. Должно быть содержаться `namespace TrabsCore`, а не `namespace TransCore.Abstract`, например, и 2. Должен быть у классов модификатор `public`

Comment: @Mirdin это я проверял первым делом.

Comment: Это Shared Library, новый тип проекта в 2015 студии.

Comment: @VladD а я подумал, "SHproj" - дополнительно расширение для SHarpa :D Так что мне с ним сделать? Сильно менять проект не хочется, он задействован в другом решении, в другой IDE и даже на другой ОС...

Comment: @VladD пересоздам проект в class library, если не найдётся решения для такого типа проекта по причине, описанной выше.

Comment: Попробуйте указать полностью `TransCore.Abstract.IWindowController`, сейчас проверил на своем компьютере, у меня срабатывает

Comment: Решение должно быть, поищите какой-нибудь _using shared projects in Visual Studio_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Третий, Shared Project, я добавил к решению давно, возможно, Visual Studio не добавил к использованию новые файлы, хотя отображает их. Переборка проекта ничего не дала, а вот полное его удаление из решения и добавление по-новой поставило всё на свои места (с этого и надо было начинать...). Надеюсь, у Visual Studio есть в запасе более элегантный способ обновления проекта.